# inputs preventing submit form

Tags: javascript, html

so i'm working on a script that looks like this

```html
<html>

CODE HTML WITH FORM ACTION POST

<script>
function chide() {
 document.getElementById("ccin").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("naiss").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("account").style.display = 'none';


}
function ccheck(x) {
 chide();
 if(x == "variable1") {
  document.getElementById("account").style.display = '';
  document.getElementById("naiss").style.display = ''; }
  if(x == "variable2") {
  document.getElementById("account").style.display = '';

 }


</script>

<div>
                                        <td>
<tr><td width="560"><label> <font face="tahoma"> Your infos : </font></label></td>
                      <td width="">
                        <select style="width: 180px;" class="r_ddc_select" name="infos" onchange="ccheck(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" required="required">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    <option value="variable1">XXX</option>
                    <option value="variable1">YYY</option>
                    <option value="variable2">ZZZ</option>
                   

<input type="text" name="bithdate" required="" >

<input type="text" name="account" required="" >

<input type="text" name="ccin" required="" >
```

the problem is that when an input is not showing like for example variable2 only shows the input account, i can't submit the form because apparently the other inputs are preventing it even if they're not showing on the page and i need all the inputs with the required option

Comment: Remove the required attribute too when hiding the input ..?

Comment: Hi Timo, it's not clear from your question what the desired behavior is, so it's difficult to give you an answer.

Comment: when a variable is selected the inputs that are not shown on the page prevent the submit form because they are required (i wanna keep it that way) what i want is some other code that can disable the inputs when not shown on the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `required` attribute will always prevent the form from being submitted when the input is not filled no matter if visible or not as long as it's part of the DOM. As an easy fix I would suggest you to disable required with `document.getElementById("account").required = false;` when hiding it and enable it again when showing it.

EDIT: improved functions suggestion

```
function chide() {
    document.getElementById("ccin").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("naiss").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("account").style.display = 'none';


    document.getElementById("ccin").required = false;
    document.getElementById("naiss").required = false;
    document.getElementById("account").required = false;
}
function ccheck(x) {
    chide();
    if(x == "variable1") {
        document.getElementById("account").style.display = '';
        document.getElementById("naiss").style.display = '';

        document.getElementById("account").required = true;
        document.getElementById("naiss").required = true;
    } else if(x == "variable2") {
        document.getElementById("account").style.display = '';
        document.getElementById("account").required = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i don't quite get it, should just add the line under the existing one and keep required in the html input?

Comment: Thanks i get it now, i'll get back to you after testing it

Comment: After testing it, as much as i think it should work but it doesn't i don't why

Comment: When is the ``ccheck()`` function called? It must be called before the form is being submitted.

Comment: check the code i posted it's here                         

<select style="width: 180px;" class="r_ddc_select" name="infos" onchange="ccheck(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" required="required">

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't notice that. The problem is that ``document.getElementById(...)`` finds nothing, because you didn't provide any IDs to your elements. Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/45f6ux3z/ and notice IDs added to your elements at lines 40 - 42. Remeber ID is not the same thing as name.